# Symfony DataTransformers with choice forms

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms

I made a DataTransformer that is made to basically NOT the available choices with the submitted ones.

My issue is that my transformer receives either `['INFO' => 'INFO', 'WARN' => 'WARN']` or `[0 => 'INFO', 1 => 'WARN']`. This usually happens when all the checkboxes are unchecked (AKA the model data of the choice is ['INFO', 'WARN']) and that I check any and submit the form.

I am using Symfony 2.6.6.

Here is the form :

```php
$choice = $builder->create('choice', 'choice', array(
    'choices' => array(
        'INFO' => 'INFO',
        'WARN' => 'WARN'
    ),
    'multiple' => true,
    'expanded' => true
);
$choice->addModelTransformer(new ReverseChoiceFieldTransformer($choice));
$builder->add($choice);
```

And here is the transformer :

```php
class ReverseChoiceFieldTransformer implements DataTransformerInterface {
    private $choices;

    public function __construct(FormBuilderInterface $fbi) {
        $this->choices = $fbi->getOption('choices');
    }

    public function transform($value) {
        return $this->reverseTransform($value);
    }

    public function reverseTransform($value) {
        return $value === '' ? null : array_diff_key($this->choices, $value);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm failing to understand your question and problem?

Comment: @tftd I wanted to create a DataTransformer that could allow to save in my model the inverse of what the user ticked in the form. My issue is that sometimes I recieve numeric indexes instead of the ones that I have in the choices for my form element, which seems unexpected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not quite sure why you'd want to use a `DataTransformer` in this case. They're used to simplify complex forms where the entered form data has to be transformed into something else. You might want to checkout the official [documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/data_transformers.html#creating-the-transformer) of Symfony, regarding Data Transformers.

Furthermore, your `ReverseChoiceFieldTransformer` class is not correctly implemented. The `transform` method is meant to transform an `Object` to a simple type like `string`,`int`,etc which is later displayed in the form as `ViewData`. On the contrary, the `reverseTransform` method is used to reverse transform the data from simple type back into the same `Object`. You can see this in the illustration below (taken from Symfony official docs)

[image: Model and View Transformers]

Having said that, I believe your approach to the problem might be wrong. It would probably better if you do this in the controller or in a form event. Here's an example of how to get the data in your controller class:

```
// MyFormType
class MyFormType extends AbstractType {

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('choice', 'choice', array(
            'choices' => array(
                'INFO' => 'Info label',
                'WARN' => 'Warn label',
                'CRIT' => 'Crit label',
            ),
            'multiple' => true,
            'expanded' => true,
            'required' => false,
            'mapped'   => false
        ))
        ->add('submit', 'submit', array(
            'attr' => array('class' => 'save'),
        ));;
    }

    public function getName() {
        return "my_form";
    }
}
```

---

```
// MyController
class MyController extends Controller {
    /**
     * @Route("/test")
     * @Template()
     */
    public function testAction(Request $request) {
        $form = $this->createForm(new MyFormType());
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if($form->isValid())
        {
            // Get selected
            $selectedChoices = $form->get('choice')->getData();
            // outputs the checked values, i.e.
            // array (size=2)
            //    0 => string 'INFO' (length=4)
            //    1 => string 'WARN' (length=4)

            // All choices with their labels
            $allChoices = $form->get('choice')->getConfig()->getOption('choices');
            // outputs all choices, i.e.
            // array (size=3)
            //   'INFO' => string 'Info label' (length=10)
            //   'WARN' => string 'Warn label' (length=10)
            //   'CRIT' => string 'Crit label' (length=10)

            // All unchecked choices. Pay attention to the difference
            // in the arrays.
            $unchecked = array_diff(array_keys($allChoices), array_values($selectedChoices));

        }

        return array('form' => $form->createView());
    }
}
```

Follow up on comments:

You're partly correct. The `transform` method receives the model data which was used to build the form, while the `reverseTransform` method receives the data submitted to the form. Although in your case the received data in both cases is an `array`, the `array` itself contains different data structure:

1. `transform` will receive:

   ```
   array (
       'INFO' => 'Info label',
       'WARN' => 'Warn label',
       'CRIT' => 'Crit label'
   )
   ```
2. `reverseTransform` will receive the checked choices i.e.:

   ```
   array (
       0 => 'INFO',
       1 => 'CRIT'
   )
   ```

Although, I would go for a controller or research if this could be done with [FormEvents](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/form/form_events.html), the following code should do the work:

```
class ReverseChoiceFieldTransformer implements DataTransformerInterface {
    private $choices;

    public function __construct(FormBuilderInterface $fbi) {
        $this->choices = $fbi->getOption('choices');
    }

    /**
     * The received data from the FormBuilder will be passed "AS IS"
     *
     * @param mixed $value
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function transform($value) {
        return $value;
    }

    /**
     * The received data from the submitted from will be modified. Doing
     * $form->get('choice')->getData() in the controller will return only
     * the unselected choices.
     *
     * @param mixed $value
     * @return null|array
     */
    public function reverseTransform($value) {
        return $value === '' ? null : array_diff(array_keys($this->choices),array_values($value));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your detailed answer. However one of the goals of doing a transformer was to avoid writing processing code in a controller, as I will be re-using this FormType, which is why the transformer seemed ideal (and does work when I do not have this numeric keys issue). Also, about the wrong transformer implementation, is it still wrong since both the view data and the model data are arrays ?