# Add CollectionType to form with predefined data

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I want to add a `CollectionType` based on a `FormType` named `SectionCaseType` to a form. In addition, I have another entity named `TypeSection` with all the posible section types for the `CollectionType` (introduction, summary, discussion, bibliography, etc.).

So the thing is that I don't know how to print all the options for the `CollectionType` from the beginning (I don't need the user can add or delete section as they are predefined).

Here is my code:

#### ClinicalCaseType

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    { 

        $builder
        ->add('title')
        ->add('sections', CollectionType::class, array(
            'entry_type' => SectionCaseType::class,
            ));
    }
```

#### SectionCaseType

Here is where I suppose I should add the code for repeat the `CollectionType` for each row in `TypeSection` entity or maybe my approach to the problem is wrong.

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {  

        $builder
        ->add('text');
    }
```

#### TypeSection

```
class TypeSection
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     *
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="SectionCase", mappedBy="type")
     */
    private $sections;  

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will probably want to add a data transformer with a Choice field. Here is a similar issue which can be adapted to solve your issue.

[Symfony DataTransformers with choice forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29656657/symfony-datatransformers-with-choice-forms)